# SQL - Making 4 new columns in a result from another column

Tags: sql

So, I'm making a data base for my college class, it's about a foreign languages school, and I need to ( using a single query ), have a number of people that are attending a certain language class, but it has to be seperated by the age group. For example, this is how the result table should look like:

Language | 14-25 | 25-35 | 35-50 | 50+ |

German  |    1  |   0   |    0  |  0  |

Italian  |    2  |   1   |    0  |  0  |

English  |    5  |   0   |    0  |  0  |

I need to do this by joining the tables "Class" that has attributes (Language, Number of students), and "Student" that has attributes (ID, name, surname, age, prior knowledge ( eg. A1, B2, ... ))

So I somehow have to figure out in which age group a certain individual goes to, then if he goes there, increment the number of students for that age group by one.

Comment: do you have a table linking Student to Class?

Comment: yes, sorry I forgot about it. It's called "Student_Class" and it has attributes (Student_ID, Class language).

Comment: Break it down and then solve in pieces, then rebuild. Here's one method to count ages... sum(case when age between 14 and 25 then 1 else 0 end) as age_14_25,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the sum and group the entries using `CASE WHEN`, so your query will look like this:

```
SELECT c.language, 
SUM(CASE WHEN s.age BETWEEN 14 AND 25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '14-25',
SUM(CASE WHEN s.age BETWEEN 25 AND 35 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '25-35',
SUM(CASE WHEN s.age BETWEEN 35 AND 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '35-50',
SUM(CASE WHEN s.age >= 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '50+'
FROM class c 
JOIN student_class sc ON c.language = sc.class_language
JOIN student s ON s.id = sc.student_id
GROUP BY c.language;
```

You have to take care because as example a person whose age is 25 will be selected in both groups "15-25" and "25-35". If this is not intended, you could do something like this:

```
...SUM(CASE WHEN s.age BETWEEN 14 AND 25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '14-25',
SUM(CASE WHEN s.age BETWEEN 26 AND 35 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '25-35',
SUM(CASE WHEN s.age BETWEEN 36 AND 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '35-50',
SUM(CASE WHEN s.age > 50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '50+'...
```

Please see the working example here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cc18f2e64f520dcdcdd8f8a927b025c2)

You could add an ORDER BY c.language at the end if you want.

A last note: The column aliases shown here ('14-25' etc.) will not work on every DB type and might be replaced depending on DB type and personal "taste".

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell is which dbms this is for.

Comment: Thank you very much, the CASE WHEN worked. When I used IIF as @TZHX said, I got some error that the function doesn't exist. Maybe it doesn't in PostgreSQL which I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a table called something like `ClassStudent` which is linking the individual students to the class (which you absolutely need to fulfil this requirement)...

```sql
SELECT c.Language,
    [14-25] = SUM(IIF(s.age BETWEEN 14 AND 25, 1, 0)),
    [25-35] = SUM(IIF(s.age BETWEEN 25 AND 35, 1, 0)),
    [35-50] = SUM(IIF(s.age BETWEEN 35 AND 50, 1, 0)),
    [50+] = SUM(IIF(s.age >= 50, 1, 0)),
FROM Class c
INNER JOIN ClassStudent cs ON c.Language = cs.Language /* you need this table */
INNER JOIN Student s ON cs.StudentID = s.ID
GROUP BY c.Language
```

Here, `IIF` is like a ternary operator in SQL form, and the `SUM` lets you count up where the condition is met.

Comment: Thanks, I've actually never seen the IIF function, I don't think I would've figured out this on my own. I see how it works, but when I write it out I get some syntax errors: 

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
LINE 2:  [14-25] = SUM(IIF("Polaznik"."Broj godina polaznika" BETWEE...
         ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 26

I don't think I made a typo.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell is which dbms this is for.

Comment: Sorry, it's PostgreSQL 14, didn't know there was much difference between different DBMS's